# Show callout for disclosureindicator for MKAnnotationView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview, calloutview

I am able to show a disclosure icon in on my map annotation using the following code.

```
  annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```

When you press the disclosure icon, it blinks but nothing else happens.  I tried putting a button handler on it but it is not a button so the compiler said no.  Do I have to create a whole gesturerecognizer to get it to do anything or how would I get a press on the the indicator to show information about the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
   annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, 
   calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
```

with

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

Comment: One question if you come back to this.  Is there a recommended way to create a view when the disclosure control is tapped to show additional information such as a small callout view to the calloutview or an expanded calloutview?  All I want to do is show a  address and phone number.  Are we supposed to make a new view ourselves and display it or is there something built in?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
   btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnDisclosureAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
   annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

    @objc func btnDisclosureAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // you action
    }
```

Comment: Hey, can anyone let me know what's wrong with this code, just want to understand  how people downvote answers